# Jackson Date is adjusted with timezone after deserialisation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialisation a JSON file and use it for unit test. But the test failed due to unmatched values.
When I look into the log, the time i got from the deserialsed object is 8 hours later than what I expect. I think it applied my timezone to the value (GMT+8).
The test passed if I set the time to 8 hours earilier in the JSON file. But I would like to get the correct time without timezone so that I don't have to make my data timezone dependant.

Here are some sample codes:
result.JSON

```
{
    "userId" : 1,
    "lastVisit" : 1546300800000
}
```

testUserData.java

```
public void checkUserData() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    UserData expected = om.readValue(new File("result.JSON"), UserData.class);
    long lastVisit = 1546300800 * 1000; //2019-01-01 00:00:00 in millisecond
    UserData actual = new UserData(1, lastVisit);
    ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

UserData.java

```
import java.util.Date;

public int userId;
public Date lastVisit;

public UserData(int userId, long lastVisitTime) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.lastVisit = new Date(lastVisitTime);
}
```

unit test log (excerpt):

```
--- Found following differences ---
lastVisit: expected: Tue Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 2019, actual: 2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
I have tried setting a timezone as suggested in the answer but it didn't work.
For those who have the same problem, I fixed it by setting a date format, not needing to set a timezone, and used string date instead of UNIX time:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TimeZone` to which zone date need to be Deserialized

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Comment: When I call getDeserializationConfig().getTimeZone() I can see that the timezone is indeed UTC, but the resulting time is still an adjusted one. I ended up setting a date format using setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")), without setting a timezone, and used string date instead of UNIX time then it worked.